# Nested posixgroup in OpenLDAP

Tags: authentication, ubuntu, openldap

Is it possible to nest posixgroup in OpenLDAP? If I use it for OS authentication in Ubuntu, will it still be recognized by the OS?

Comment: Define 'nest'. Your second sentence is just a tautology.

Comment: By nest I mean set a posixgroup as a member of another posixgroup entry. Is that possible?

Comment: It's possible, but services that use it may not support unravelling nested groups.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your authentication method.
If you use SSSD for authentication, you can configure it to support nested groups.

See /etc/sssd/sssd.conf:

```
ldap_group_nesting_level = 0
```

Set this to 1 or more if needed.